# on focusout set focus on the same cotrol

Tags: jquery

I have written a function on `focusout` of a textbox and want to check and focus back on the same if it is blank. It is not setting back focus.

```
<div class="controls">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="inputID" id="inputID"/>
</div>
```

```js
$('#inputID').focusout(function(e) {
    if ($(this).val()=="") {
        alert("focus onthe same")
        $(this).focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
    }
});
```

jsFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/sw91q0vk/

Comment: Your code works, you just didn't include jQuery in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sw91q0vk/1/

Comment: Try setting the focus back with a `setTimeout()`, after a very short time (like 10 ms).

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it is setting focus back to the control.

Comment: Well that's what your question says you want to do?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I want focus on the same control after the alert.

Comment: ... and that's what your code is doing.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It's is not focusing back to the textbox after alert

Comment: What broswer are you testing in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101987/discussion-between--and-rory-mccrossan).

Answer (score 1):

I think your alert box and `preventDefault` is causing the problem, your focus event is not getting fired, either use `setTimeout` or remove alert.

i have removed alert box and fiddle goes like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/punkhaa/sw91q0vk/13/)

change in code is like this

```
$('#inputID').focusout(function(e) {
  if ($(this).val()=="") {

    setTimeout(function(){
        console.log(323);
      $(this)[0].focus();
    },500)
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  });
```

Now i have removed alert, but to be honest alert is a so 2005, lets use some 2016 collection for throwing error, like notify or something, there are plenty out there.